# SwiftUI equivalent to apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent?

Tags: swiftui

In SwiftUI `.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())` will give you a `SegmentedControl` with all segments having equal size.

How do we do the SwiftUI equivalent to setting the UIKit property `apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent property in SwiftUI, 
also the PickerStyle protocol its defined internally so you have 3 options

1. Set the property globally, all segmented controls in your SwiftUI project will be affected.
   UISegmentedControl.appearance().apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = true
2. Use UIViewRepresentable to wrap the UIKit segmented control
3. make your own picker, experiments
   [SwiftUI Custom PickerStyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878987/swiftui-custom-pickerstyle)